# Setting Password Contraints on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a database but I'm trying to set a constraint on the staff password field, the rules should be that there is one capital letter in it and a number present.

For the capital letter, I've done some reading upon it and I think you need to use COLLATE to check if there is a capital letter but I am not sure how this works nor how to implement it.

For the number I think I need to use `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` but again I'm not sure what this does so if you can explain what each part does that would be great. I'm quite new to SQL server so some of this stuff I've yet to wrap my head around it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: You should NEVER store your passwords in plain text in the database anyway. They should be salted and hashed. This means that your constraint should not exist. Those checks should be done in the application that captures the password just before it salts and hashes the original value before sending it to the database.

Comment: I wish i could +100 on @SeanLange comment. Salt and Hash is something you really need to research. Side note, which do you think would take longer to break this: `Hf82&Fd097*nf` or this:`apasswordlikethiswhichicaneasilyrememberandissuperduperlong`

Comment: @scsimon I believe you are referring to this? https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: HAHAHAHA that's a great comic @SeanLange... never seen that. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback. About salting and hashing, I am currently working just from SQL server so how would I add the password salting and hashing before sending it to the database? Is that done outside the database by a different program, as I am just setting up the initial database and adding constraints and such on fields. Another question I have is, how would I create a constraint that only allowed dates and times in the future. I apologise for all the questions and stuff!